# Cannot Display Multiple Annotation Pins in MKMapView

Tags: ios, ios7, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotationview

I have a database which stores latitude and longtitude values. I want to iterate through the list and show them on the map. I have written a condition that says if the type is `atm` then the annotation color should be green and if it is `branch` it should show red.

```
if ([myNewArrayElement isEqualToString:@"BRANCH"]) {                   
    self.customAnnotation = [[BasicMapAnnotation alloc] initWithLatitude:[[record valueForKey:@"lat"]floatValue] andLongitude:[[record valueForKey:@"lon"]floatValue]] ;
    NSLog(@"Current coordinates%f%f",[[record valueForKey:@"lat"]floatValue],[[record valueForKey:@"lon"]floatValue]);
    mPinColor = @"PURPLE";

    self.customAnnotation.title = record.type;
    MKPinAnnotationView * annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:self.customAnnotation
                                                              reuseIdentifier:@"CustomAnnotation"] ;
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    mPinColor = @"";
    NSLog(@"Its Basic");
    annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;

    [self.mapView addAnnotation:self.customAnnotation];
    self.mapView.delegate = self;
}
else if ([myNewArrayElement isEqualToString:@"ATM"]) {
    self.normalAnnotation = [[BasicMapAnnotation alloc] initWithLatitude:[[record valueForKey:@"lat"]floatValue] andLongitude:[[record valueForKey:@"lon"]floatValue]] ;
    mPinColor = @"GREEN";
    self.normalAnnotation.title = record.type;
    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:self.normalAnnotation
                                                               reuseIdentifier:@"NormalAnnotation"] ;
   annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
   mPinColor = @"";
   NSLog(@"Its Basic");
   annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
   [self.mapView addAnnotation:self.normalAnnotation];

}
```

My viewForAnnotation is

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    NSLog(@"Length of mpincolor%d",mPinColor.length);
    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView;
    if ([mPinColor isEqualToString:@"PURPLE"]) {
        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"CustomAnnotation"] ;
        annotationView.canShowCallout = NO;
        NSLog(@"Its custom");
        annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
        return annotationView;
    }
    else if([mPinColor isEqualToString:@"GREEN"]) {

       annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                             reuseIdentifier:@"NormalAnnotation"] ;
       annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
       mPinColor = @"";
       NSLog(@"Its Basic");
       annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;

       return annotationView;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

I'm able to show the pins correctly, but the color is not showing properly. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a **color** property to the **BasicMapAnnotation** class. Query that property in **viewForAnnotation** to properly initialize the **pinColor**. Btw, the code you use to create annotation views outside the viewForAnnotation method doesn't make much sence as the created views aren't used.

Answer (score 1):

i recommend you to visit this site and get benefited
http://code4app.net/ios/Cluster-Annotations-MapView/4f7ffde206f6e7177a000000